# Displaying two datasets in one line chart

Tags: django, templates, chart.js

I have the following code. I am trying to display two different datasets in one line chart. I get no errors but the chart just displays one line.
Would appreciate any advice on what my be going wrong

```
var data = {
labels: jsonObject5,
datasets: [
  {
    label: "Data",
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: gradientStroke,
    borderColor: '#d048b6',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderDash: [],
    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
    pointBackgroundColor: '#d048b6',
    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#d048b6',
    pointBorderWidth: 20,
    pointHoverRadius: 4,
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
    pointRadius: 4,
    data: jsonObject4,
  },
  {
    label: "Data2",
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: gradientStroke,
    borderColor: '#d048b6',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderDash: [],
    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
    pointBackgroundColor: '#d048b6',
    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(155,255,255,0)',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#d048b6',
    pointBorderWidth: 20,
    pointHoverRadius: 4,
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
    pointRadius: 4,
    data: jsonObject6,
  }
  ]
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple
});
```

Comment: I created a test fiddle using the code of yours `https://jsfiddle.net/hfuswvqo/`, everything seems to be correct. I suspect issue with the jsonobject variables.